# How can I find good words to describe emotions or states of mind?

Tags: characters, description, conflict

For example, if I struggle with finding good words to describe being confused and in two minds, what techniques can I use to find figures of speech or adjectives?

Comment: Please don't post one-line answers in the comments. That's what the answer box is for.

Comment: Do you want to show the reader this state of mind or tell them about it? (Hint: if you're writing fiction you'll likely want to show it... which also means you don't really need these words...)

Comment: I have edited the question to make it on topic and leave it open. I have also added an answer to the new version of the question. I vote to leave it open now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to write your story for you, but maybe I can help you learn how you can solve this writing problem yourself.

When I'm struggling with how to describe a certain emotion or state of mind, I do one or all of the following:

1. Try and remember how that state of mind or emotion feels like, if I ever had it. Write that down without attempting to write well, just describe it as good as I can.

   If I have never had that emotion or state of mind, I try to imagine it, and write down what I imagine.
2. Use [Google Book search](https://books.google.com/) to find how other writers have described the emotion or state of mind. As keywords for my search I use the name of the emotion ("fear") or words from my description (see no. 1). I collect what I find in a text file.
3. Look up some of the words I have collected so far in the dictionary to find example sentences for their usage as well as paraphrases of their meaning and synonyms. I'm using an online dictionary in my mother tongue that links to a linguistic online corpus that contains many examples of the words in use.
4. In English, you might want to use a book such as *The Emotion Thesaurus* by Angela Ackerman and Becca Puglisi. It has a double page on "confusion" that lists physical signals, internal sensations, mental responses, cues of acute and long-term confusion, and cues of suppressed confusion. I won't quote from it, because that would not constitute fair use under these circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Vacillating.  Paradoxical. Contradictory. Murky. Weighing the alternatives.  Dialectical. Ruled by the goddess Eris.  Thinking out of the box. Tricky. Puzzling. Bemused.